# Ошибка 216 при попытке открыть Firefox с помощью selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
#time.sleep(25)
browser.get('www.google.com')
```

Это мой код и он по какой-то причине не работает после запуска мне выдаёт ошибку:

> "OSError: [WinError 216] Эта версия "%1" не совместима с версией Windows, работающей на этом компьютере. Проверьте сведения о системе, а затем обратитесь к издателю программного обеспечения"

Я просто не могу запустить Firefox с помощью селениума.

Comment: Обнови селениум и вебдрайвер.

Comment: У меня установлены последнии версии